# Python Tkinter: Resetting a previously defined variable with Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, connect, irc

I'm trying to make it so that when a user enters their name, password, etc, it stores it globally so that the program is able to connect with that name. I've defined the variables at top like this:

```
global server
server = ""
global nick
nick = ""
global altnick
altnick = ""
global password
password = ""
global channel
channel = ""
```

Then, when the Tkinter program comes in, the user can use the Entries to enter all the proper values:

```
networktop = Toplevel(master=root)
networktop.title("Network List")
networktop.geometry("300x220")

Label(networktop, text="Nickname:").pack()
nickbox = Entry(networktop)
nickbox.grid(column="50", row="50")
nickbox.pack()

nick = nickbox.get()

Label(networktop, text="Alternate nick:").pack()
altbox = Entry(networktop)
altbox.grid(column="50", row="50")
altbox.pack()

altnick = altbox.get()

Label(networktop, text="Password:").pack()
pwbox = Entry(networktop, show="*")
pwbox.grid(column="50", row="50")
pwbox.pack()

password = pwbox.get()

Label(networktop, text="Channel to join:").pack()
chanbox = Entry(networktop)
chanbox.grid(column="50", row="50")
chanbox.pack()

channel = chanbox.get()

listvar = StringVar(networktop)
listvar.set("Choose a network...") # default value
listnetwork = OptionMenu(networktop, listvar, "irc.freenode.net")
listnetwork.config(width="50")
listnetwork.grid(column="50", row="50")
listnetwork.pack()

server = listvar.get()

networkconnect = Button(networktop, text="Connect", command=connect)
networkcancel = Button(networktop, text="Cancel", command=networktop.destroy)
networkcancel.pack(side=LEFT)
networkconnect.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is that when something is entered in (e.g. "NickName") it replaces nick = "" at top with nick = "NickName", so that when "Connect" is pressed it would connect to the server with "NickName". But I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\irchat.py", line 29, in connect
    irc.connect((server, 6667))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

I feel like I'm being a total noob here and the solution is probably easy as pie. xD

Comment: I don't know what is your real problem is but using both `grid` and `pack` at the same parent is not a good thing. Also when you use 50,50 as your values of row and column, you are saying, place this widget to 50th row, 50th column. Since you are doing the same thing for all widgets, Tkinter would put them in the same place. So using 0,0 - 0,1(I mean different combinations)  etc.. would be much better to use depending on your design.

Comment: Additionally, your error says a lot. Probably your problem is caused by `socket` part of the code but not tkinter.

Comment: @Lafexlos oh well, I didn't think of that :P Will fix it.

As for the second, I might look into it - although I still think it's something to do with the fact that it isn't writing the variables as I intend it to.

Comment: Note: it serves no purpose to call both grid and pack on the same widget. One or the other. If you do both, only the last one you call has any effect. For example, in your code the call to `nickbox.grid` is useless since you call `nickbox.pack` right after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are getting the value of the entry widget before the user has an opportunity to enter any text. You're creating the widget and then immediately getting the value. Because of this, server is the empty string and thus the socket code is failing.

You don't want to get the value until the user has click the Connect button.